# Publish MVC website using MSBuild and CruiseControl

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to publish a MVC2 Web app as part of our continuous integration using Cruise Control ccnet.config file with msbuild. I have searched through numerous posts but cant find the right answer or get the suggestions to work. Does anyone know how to get this going so I can output the published files to a directiory ont he build server?

I have this so far:-

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe       C:\SVNWork\projectNAME_labelled\
projectNAME.csproj      /noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Release;outDir=Release\ /v:diag
ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication>

Can someone perhaps get in touch so I can ask them some questions?

Thanks Gregor

Comment: @"Gregor Suttie" any luck getting this to work, still a problem on my side. Seems like you need to install Visual Studio on the Build Server which is a complete Faux pas! Maybe we should start a bounty ??

Answer (score 0):

I have the a similar issue. The suggestions seem good although havent got it to successfully work.

[Publish MVC v1 C# application through Cruise Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433837/publish-mvc-v1-c-application-through-cruise-control)